# Django Python shell indentation error

Tags: django, shell

when i paste the below code in my python shell. I get an Indentation error.

> ... print "this is an ideal answer for both"   File "", line
>   2
>       print "this is an ideal answer for both"
>           ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
def get_match(user_a, user_b):
    user_a_answers = UserAnswer.objects.filter(user=user_a)[0]
    user_b_answers = UserAnswer.objects.filter(user=user_b)[0]
    if user_a_answers.question.id == user_b_answers.question.id:
        user_a_answer = user_a_answers.my_answer
        user_a_pref = user_a_answers.their_answer
        user_b_answer = user_b_answers.my_answer
        user_b_pref = user_b_answers.their_answer
        if user_a_answer == user_b_pref:
            print "%s fits with %s's preference" %(user_a_answers.user.username, user_b_answers.user.username)
        if user_a_pref == user_b_answer:
            print "%s fits with %s's preference" %(user_a_answers.user.username, user_b_answers.user.username)
        if user_a_answer == user_b_pref and user_a_pref == user_b_answer:
            print "this is an ideal answer for both"




get_match(mohit, saraswati)
get_match(saraswati, userc)
get_match(mohit, userc)
```

i get an indentation error , when i run this from the shell , why?`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to determine your indentation error. Because Python supports one-way indentation. You may be used Tab and spaces at a time. Please check by yourself and use only one at a time. Spaces are recommended.

Comment: the same code in running in a different shell, whereas i get